# cMake include_directories but for include command

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, clang++

I'm trying to compile a cmake c++ project as .so file to a library.

The sources of the project are now moved in to sub directory library and paths are changed through `include_directories` to reflect the new subdirectory.

Within the library, there are additional include example.cmake entries but without the new subdirectory. I had the same problem with the cpp files but that could be fixed through the change in `include_directories`.

Is there something like this path rewrite as well for cmake `include` instructions?

```
CMake Error at libdir/src/core/core.cmake:1 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    src/core/cpu.cmake
```

Comment: Despite the similarity of names, commands `include_directories` and `include` are absolutely **unrelated**. The former one specifies flags for the compiler, the latter one includes the file for CMake. There is a little specifics about `include` command: it accepts path to the file which should exist. If the path is not absolute, then it is treated relative to the current source directory. In your case CMake interprets file `src/core/cpu.cmake` as `libdir/src/core/src/core/cpu.cmake`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation @Tsyvarev! I got this now working through a hacky simlink...